# optimistic lock versus pessimistic lock for updating a shared account

Tags: database, oracle11g

we have a very high transactional system and want to update an financial account .every transaction may update this account.we use optimistic lock ( @version). but fail is very high. 
our db is oracle11g. is there any other solution.?locking entire row?

Comment: I'm removing the Java tag from this, because the question seems to have nothing to do with Java. If it does, please edit the question to explain the Java connection.

Comment: Is your application architecture such that you could lock the entire row easily?  If you've got a bog standard 3-tier application, the intention is that the database connections are stateless.  Allowing row locks (and thus transactions) to span multiple database requests would be possible but would involve major changes.  Explicit locking would also force concurrency if you have many threads all blocking on access to that one account, severely limiting scalability.  Are you certain that every transaction needs to update a single row rather than writing independent transaction logs?